# Object methods passing Object Methods what's the syntax?

Tags: javascript

Using KineticJS I figured out how to pass a function as the Gameboard function but all the this's inside the Gameboard function think's its now the object that got the function :(.

```
function Gameboard(){
//.... creates placeholders for stage layers and all objects
this.dice_layer=new Kinetic.Layer();

this.rolldice=function(){
     alert(this.toString());
     //..alter images
     this.dice_layer.draw();//<~~ thinks this is circle once passed through setUpGameBoard says dice_layer is undefined.  alert(this.toString()); shows this to be circle.
};


this.setUpGameBoard=function(){
   // ...draws board pawns creates a circle object
   var obj=this;//<~~ are there memory issues with this?  Is there a better way?
    circle.on("click",**obj**.rolldice.**bind**(obj);//** == ANSWER!!!!


 };
```

};

Comment: Also read about `this`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Comment: Please clarify what "doesn't work" means - is there an error in the console?

Comment: My problem has been solved!! Thank you Dennis and Nadir.  I'm originally from .NET world and Java so having functions instead of methods is going to take a little mind separation but with you two's help I think I've taken a large step forward.  I don't have the Reputation to vote sorry.  It probably would require another question but I was curious would it be better to var obj=this// Gameboard as a Gameboard variable or declare that in the functions?  Are there memory issues with it?

Comment: is `circle.on...` contained in another function?

Comment: the .on function came from KineticJS framework from Kinetic.Node.on circle was Kinetic.Node.Shape.Circle at least from my understanding of OOP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
    this.doSomething=function(fnction){
```

You are declaring `doSomething` as a function with a single parameter, `fnction` but when you call it, you are passing two - a string and a function.

```
    this.doSomething=function(str, fnction){
```

will behave as you expect it.

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BH2QJ/)

---

Based on your "solution" to the second problem, it looks like you want to use ES5's [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).  It allows to you specify the `this` for a particular function call since JavaScript really doesn't have "methods", you have to specify the object they operate on.

```
 this.barfoo.doSomething(this.doBar.bind(this));
```

An [example of malfunctioning](http://jsfiddle.net/BH2QJ/3/) code can be compared to the [fix with bind](http://jsfiddle.net/BH2QJ/2/).

Comment: Sorry that was a typo the original object had a string object "click".  I think i fixed it just trying to recreate the problem very simply.

Comment: Without the global function I can't get the bar.foo.doSomething(fnction) to take bar.doSomething is the  this.barfoo.doSomething(this.doBar); the correct syntax and should behave as expected? For some reason it crashes on me making all other bar objects useless.

Comment: this.barfoo.doSomething(bar.doSomething.bind(this));  gave me doSomething is not defined

Comment: To make the question more clear because you've offered examples that clearly work I'm using KineticJS I have a Stage->Layer->Circle Gameboard is the object with the instances and when I click the circle I'd like to send the Gameboad function this.rolldice() but I fail without the global functions.  circle.on("click",this.rolldice); is not working neither is circle.on("click",this.rolldice.bind(this));

Comment: bar is the constructor function. bar.doSomething doesn't exist because doSomething only on instances of `foo`.

Comment: It's going to be very hard to debug your code without actually seeing your code.

Comment: sorry I meant this.barfoo.doSomething(this.doSomething.bind(this));

Comment: I'm sort of new asking questions for javascript and frameworks I apologize and greatly appreciate your continued feed back.  I edited the question

Comment: Thank you I figured it out with your's and Nadirs's help. this changes even in the scope of the variables origination. This is terribly confusing if I create a function in Gameboard and send that function to circle it only gets access to circles attributes unless I bind Gameboard to the function. You allowed me to understand bind and without that I would have only taken one-stop forward only to be stopped again!

Answer (score 0):

Probably your simplification doesn't show up the real issue. I guess something like the following would be more similar to your problem:

```
function foo(){
    this.doSomething = function(fnction){
        fnction();
   };
}

function bar(){
    this.myField = "Buzz"
    this.barfoo = new foo();
    this.doBar = function(){
        alert(this.myField);
    };
    this.barfoo.doSomething(this.doBar); // tried this
    //this.barfoo.doSomething(this.doBar());  also tried this  
    //this.barfoo.doSomething(bar.doBar);  also tried this  
    //this.barfoo.doSomething(bar.doBar());  also tried this  
}
```

Where you can notice issues in accessing `this`-related properties.

If this is actually the problem, then you should be able to solve it by using either `call` or `apply` in `foo`'s `doSomething` method:

```
function foo() {
  this.doSomething = function (obj, fn) {
    fn.call(obj);
  };
}
```

And this is how you will use it in `bar`:

```
function bar() {
  this.myField = "Buzz";
  this.barfoo = new foo();
  this.doBar = function () {
    alert(this.myField);
  };
  this.barfoo.doSomething(this, this.doBar);
}

var myBar = new bar();
```

Check the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wNBb/1/).

Comment: Thank you for your help unfortunately foo is part of a framework and I fear altering it would be far more difficult.  Which might mean I can only use global as I am doing now I was hoping for a better solution.  I'm using KineticJS I have a Stage->Layer->Circle Gameboard is the object with the instances and when I click the circle I'd like to send the Gameboad function this.rolldice() but I fail without the global functions. circle.on("click",this.rolldice); is not working neither is circle.on("click",this.rolldice.bind(this)); as Dennis had suggested

Comment: maybe something like `circle.on("click", function () { this.rolldice(); })` or `circle.on("click", function () { this.rolldice.call(this); })` would work?

Comment: once inside circle.on("click", function(){ this<~~ refers to circle  I think that is also the problem with circle.on("click", this.<~~ also refers to circle  ..... you just helped me figure it out!!!!! but it still doesn't kind of work hmm

Comment: you *think* or you *know*? Since it's a closure, `this` should be bound to the object it was created in (i.e. `bar`).

Comment: I don't know javascript I know it wasn't referring to gameboard lol sorry new to javascript.  I got it to go to the function by var obj=this; circle.on("click",obj.rolldice);  Just now it doesn't see the layers of the gameboard.

Comment: Thank you I figured it out with your's and Dennis's help.  this changes even in the scope of the variables origination.  This is terribly confusing if I create a function in Gameboard and send that function to circle it only gets access to circles attributes unless I bind Gameboard to the function.  You allowed me to understand the scope of the word this and for that I"m grateful!

Comment: Always glad to help. You should post an answer of your own (you can auto-accept it), so other people that will have a question like yours will find the solution.